# DAX: Using CONTAINSSTRING() to find strings that contains a single letter not a part of a word

Tags: dax

Let's say I have a column with product names.

Inside the column with product names, the products are given a letter to represent how well the product are selling, either A, B or C. (Ex. `"B Black Charlie Shoes"`)

The letter doesn't necessarily appear before the product name. So sometimes the letters can appear inside or at the end of the string. (Ex. `"Black Charlie Shoes B"` or `"Black Charlie B Shoes"`)

I want to be able to classify if a string contains "B" without being a part of a word somewhere inside the string, but I run into some problems.

If I want to find the strings which starts with "B" then I might write the following DAX expression:

```
CONTAINSSTRINGEXACT('Products'[PRODUCT_NAME],"B ")
```

*Note the space after the letter B*

This will catch all the product names that have a "B" followed by the actual names. However, this will also wrongly catch product names that ends on a "B" (Ex. `"Chelsea COLLAB Shoes"`) since COLLAB ends on a "B".

To my understanding DAX doesn't allow for the use of regular expressions, so how do I specify that I'm only interested in letters that stands alone (not a part of a word)?

Comment: You're best using PQ/M for this rather than DAX as it is a data shaping exercise. Ideally, you want a new column with the classification in there.

Comment: Can PQ/M perform regular expressions? My initial idea was to create a column in DAX using an IF statement.

Comment: It can but not easily. You don't need a regular expression though. You can pad the start and end with a space and then search for " B " to get B classifications etc.

Comment: The problem with that solution is that It won't catch products that have the letter at the start, since the string doesn't start with a space before the letter, and leaving the space out causes the problem described above.

Comment: That is why I said to pad the start and end with a space.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you are saying. Wouldn't adding the space in front of the letter make the expression unable to catch the letter in ex. this string `"B Black Charlie Shoes"` since the string doesn't start with a space?

Comment: I'll post a PQ solution for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this.

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WclJwyklMzlZwzkgsyslMVQjOyE8tVorVAcpgiis4Ick4oeuJBQA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Column1 = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each " " & [Column1] & " "),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Classification", each if Text.Contains([Custom], " B ") then "B" else null),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Custom"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Comment: Ahh now I know what you meant by 'pad'. Thanks, that solves the problem!